# linq to sql query with checkboxes where condition combination

Tags: c#, linq

if checkbox  chkAus checked :

```
if (chkAus.Checked)
                {
                    vAdvanceSearchResults  = (from t in vAdvanceSearchResults
                                    join imp in _bDataContext.Imprints on t.ImprintID equals imp.ID
                                    join cc in _bDataContext.CountryCodes on imp.CountryID equals cc.ID
                                    where cc.Code.Contains("AU")
                                    select t).Distinct();**
                }
```

if chkAus and chkNz are checked

```
if (chkNz.Checked && chkAus.Checked)
            {
                vAdvanceSearchResults = (from t in vAdvanceSearchResults
                                join imp in _bDataContext.Imprints on t.ImprintID equals imp.ID
                                join cc in _bDataContext.CountryCodes on imp.CountryID equals cc.ID
                                where cc.Code.Contains("AU") || cc.Code.Contains("NZ")
                                select t).Distinct();
            }
```

The condition on linq query changes as the checkboxes are checked.

```
where cc.Code.Contains("AU") || cc.Code.Contains("NZ")
```

I have nearly 10 checkboxes, and got stuck on how to write that many conditions.
Any help please.

for example if there is **chkUS** :
then the combination with **chkAus,chkNz,chkUS** checkboxes the linq query would change.

```
where cc.Code.Contains("AU") || cc.Code.Contains("NZ") || cc.Code.Contains("US")
```

Comment: if chkAU checked and chkNZ not checked then cc.Code == "AU", and both are checked cc.Code == "AU" || cc.Code == "NZ"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put all of them in a list and then do a if list.contains(cc.Code)

```
var a = new List<string>(){"AU","NZ","US"};
var linq =  (from t in vAdvanceSearchResults
                                join imp in _bDataContext.Imprints on t.ImprintID equals imp.ID
                                join cc in _bDataContext.CountryCodes on imp.CountryID equals cc.ID
                                where a.Contains(cc.Code)
                                select t).Distinct();
```

Comment: The op's two queries are the same.  The list contains allows the country code to be any of them.  If the query needed to be different based upon one or the other, then it would be different.  Rather this is just a boolean test really, that the code is equal to any of the list items.

Comment: Actually no, here is c# fiddle, the list.contains will only return on exact matches.   https://dotnetfiddle.net/H5w7kr

Answer (score 1):

Create a list of selected checkboxes first. Like this.

```
var selectedCountries = new List<string>();
if (chkAus.Checked) selectedCountries.Add("AU");
if (chkNz.Checked) selectedCountries.Add("NZ");
if (chkUs.Checked) selectedCountries.Add("US");
//... And so on
```

And then modify your linq query to check whether this list contains the code or not, I mean reversing the comparison is an answer. Make sure you remove if condition for this linq query.

```
vAdvanceSearchResults = (from t in vAdvanceSearchResults 
    join imp in _bDataContext.Imprints on t.ImprintID equals imp.ID 
    join cc in _bDataContext.CountryCodes on imp.CountryID equals cc.ID
    where  selectedCountries.Contains(cc.Code)
    select t).Distinct();
```

This will fix your problem.